# OK to not vertically center TV wall mounting plate?

Tags: mounting, television

I have recently purchased this TV which I am hoping to wall mount (with an articulating arm):

https://www.lg.com/us/tvs/lg-55UK7700PUD-4k-uhd-tv

Per the specs, the TV is compatible with VESA 300x300 mounts. Take a look at the 4th and 6th images at the link above, and you may notice my problem. Any mount that extends to fit 400x400 (or more), if installed perfectly centered with the mount points, will run into the protruding part at the bottom of the TV. I haven't yet found a mount that would fit my TV that wouldn't require such an extension.

It seems that `X`-style mounts are out of the question. My question is if I get a rectangular-style mount with a 400x400 extension, would there be any long-term issues (stress, etc.) with mounting it above-center vertically, where I would use the "400mm" points at the bottom of the mount and "200mm" points at the top of the mount? For example, just to pick a mount, if I were to get something like [https://www.amazon.com/Mounting-Dream-Bracket-Articulating-400x400mm/dp/B00QOOZ4DE](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00QOOZ4DE), could this be (properly) installed on the TV above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be no problem using the mount linked to mount that TV.  The TV is only 35 pounds and most mounts are over engineered for their weights and the mount listed will handle 60 pounds.